How to measure the vibration of an object on a video shot at high speed camera?
I have a video fragment which I split into frames (pictures). I use them in pairs (1 frame with 2, 2 with 3, etc.) to find shifts on x and y axes (i.e. how much I need to shift 1 frame to make it like 2). And based on these values I want to calculate the vibration (in hertz) of the object from the video. How can I connect these ideas? And if there is another approach to calculate the vibration of an object with video, what is it? Thanks!
I have no idea how to implement this yet, so far I have found frame-by-frame shifts (applying 2d fft). Now I'm thinking how I can use (or if there is another approach) frame-by-frame shifts to measure the vibration of the object. I will implement everything in python

Not really anything I've done, but chapter 3 of Chen's PhD addresses a similar problem for non-contact building inspection using vibration measurements from video.
The relevant chapter has this pipeline which might be instructive:

